# building .deb file using dpkg-deb, unable to set permission that I need

Tags: debian, dpkg, chmod

I have built a Python applicaton for the internal use within the company using Pyinstaller. Now I want to export it as .deb package for people to install. The file tree, excluding the source files, which I do not need to have in the .deb, looks like this:

```
- DEBIAN/
    - rules
    - control
- /opt/                        <-- I want my app to sit in /opt/
    - dist/                    <-- This is what I want to distribute essentially
        - my_project           <-- An executable Python app
        - _internal/           <-- Shared libraries needed for Python app sit here
            - shared_lib1.so
            - shared_lib2.so
            - .....
        - resources/
            - images/
                - my_image.png
            - info/
                - info.json
                - warning.txt
        - configuration_files/
            - configA.json
            - configB.json
        - logs/                             <-- Logs generated by Python app
            - my_project_log_20240125.log
            - my_project_log_20240124.log
            - ...
- /usr/
    - share/
        - applications/
            my_project.desktop              <-- Dekstop entry
```

Building .deb file works well and installation works well, with one exception: My Python app, every time it is installed/reinstalled requires at least chmod 757 /opt/dist/logs to be able to write logs, otherwise, 'Permission Denied'. It means, that every time, I have to do it manually.

If I set chmod 757 /opt/dist/logs before building package with dpkg-deb, I get the following error:

```
dpkg-deb error: control directory has bad permissions 757 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)
```

Meaning, that I cannot have anyone who installs the app run it without setting /opt/dist/logs to have 757 rights.

I do not want to write logs locally in the user, because any other users will likely need to access the logs. Also, every user will be able to run the app, meaning that every user should be able to write these logs. I do not want my files to be scattered around, like having shared libraries in one directory, executable in different, logs in third, otherwise, it is difficult to find something that I need, I need to search through everywhere, because I, after few months, may forget, where I was holding e.g. resources files and everything is not in one place. I do not want to adjust any log writing paths, as it should be done relatively to the executable, as the app is going to be built for windows as well, meaning, if I would have to implement multiple different log paths for windows and debian, which is pain.

Can someone tell me, what can I do? Is my approach in building .deb file fundamentally wrong? I can't set permission automatically, even though I need them to write Python log files and I need log files to be together with executable, because executable searches for logs in the same location as the executable is placed.

Comment: You can do the chmod in a postinst script. See Debian's [Basics of the Packaging System](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html). But it's still a bad idea to have a world writable directory - and you will need to make sure different users write to different log files, which sort of defies the idea of having a central log directory.

Comment: I will try postinst, but I still not a fan of this. Anyway, I need everything to be written in the same log directory and same log file, regardless of user though, it is out of question, as it would vastly complicate things for me.

Comment: Couldn’t you use `syslog` to log, and avoid the problem entirely?

Comment: I'd rather not redo all of the logging mechanism that interacts with my app, the app is built for both linux and windows and there would be complications and inside the app it does a little bit more than plain logging...

Comment: Yes but the way it currently is written is actually bad for Linux, so you're not losing compatibility with an operating system. There's syslog for Windows.